# Ajax Post Method is not Hitting in tridion gui Extension

Tags: 2011, 2013, core-service, cme, gui-extensions

i am Creating GUI Extension in tridion.i have loaded jquery.js by editor config for my  Extension.i have also coded my Service.svc file having some operation contract and it is implemented too now i am trying to call post method of Ajax of jquery from ui but my xmlHttpRequst object is failing to send Data to server.is there is any restriction for ajax operarion or do we have to register all js script into parent class?...
as in javascript (namespace pattern) it get used ..

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void GetCount(string Id,out string strResult);
```

implementation:

```
public void GetCount(string Id, out string strResult)
    {
        //Id = "tcm:23-43434";
        //apply logic here
        strResult = "Result of Logic";
    }

    $j.ajax({               
    url: "http://localhost:20263/Service.svc?Id"+tcmID,
    type: POST,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success:  function (result)
    {
        //unable to send request to server....[[[Error]]]
        [[[[[[Error]]]]]]...
    },
    error: fail,
    dataFilter: function (data)
    {
    }
});
```

this jquery Ajax code is hitting my service method proper in sample web Application...but when i added same svc with tridion gui extension it is not hiting...

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Is it a cross-domain issue?  What does your browser console window say?

Comment: yes it is cross domain,robrtc..hey rob i copied ajax code to hit it not working..if i add in same project how to call....

Comment: This could be the problem then.  Can you deploy your Web Service under the Tridion IIS Website and therefore it would not be cross domain?  Or, add CORS to the C# web service and also jQuery?  I've lost a lot of time before with these cross domain issues and sometimes hosting it under the Tridion CMS website is the easiest.

Comment: robrtc do you have any links to call service form jquery code to web service into the tridion and its steps...i seen usually they are using GET Method of AJAX..to request server...every where they are registering name spaces

Comment: Another idea could be that your popup is a Web App (not .html with jQuery) and then you pass the WebApp the URIs of items you want to process, and use Core Service within the WebApp to do the work.

Comment: i am just creating on html div which i appended to parent dashboard div and applied some animation now it is working also but i m getting problem while making call to service for my extension if you know to call service in existing extension...what source we have to add any link please share

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not trying to use jQuery for this.

It is unnecessary as there is already a framework available that provides you with everything you need to call your web service model.

In fact, as soon as you configure the service in your model, a proxy JavaScript object is automatically created that allows you to call the web methods and handle success & failure. It is named the same as the fully qualified name of your web service, but with lowercase letters for the namespace.

The process for creating your own model is pretty simple and is documented on the following page (requires login):  [Creating a Data Model](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_1D238127D92443FFAEACE7D5ED4A5B58)